# In Activity/Fragment, How to get/wait the return value from ViewModel coroutines operation?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

Following the codelab demo from Google ([link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#8)), I try to refactor my code to ViewModel + coroutines. My question is, instead of just insert the data ([original code](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordViewModel.kt#L59)), I want to wait for the result from the inserting operation, which should return the id if the inserting succeeded, then do something based on the result. So how to do it?

Currently, I send a method to the ViewModel insert method as a callback. Of course, observing the ViewModel is another option. But is there any better solution?

My current code:

EventActivity:

```
viewModel.insert(Event("name"), {
    if (it == -1L) {
        Log.i("insert", "failure")
    } else {
        Log.i("insert", "success: $it")
    }
})
```

EventViewModel:

```
private val mEventDao: EventDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application).eventDao()
private val mJob = Job()
private val mScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + mJob)

fun insert(event: Event, callback: (id: Long) -> Unit) {
    mScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val result =
            try {
                // just for testing delay situation
                delay(5000)
                val id = mEventDao.insertEvent(event)
                id
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                -1L
            }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            callback(result)
        }
    }
}
```

EventDao:

```
@Dao
interface EventDao {
    fun insertEvent(event: Event): Long
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `LiveData` object to `EventViewModel`, update it when inserting is done and subscribe to it in `Activity`:

```
class EventViewModel : ViewModel() {
    //...
    var insertionId = MutableLiveData<Long>()

    fun insert(event: String) {
        mScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val result =
                    try {
                        // just for testing delay situation
                        delay(5000)
                        val id = mEventDao.insertEvent(event)
                        id
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        -1L
                    }

            insertionId.postValue(result)
        }
    }
}
```

And subscribe in the `EventActivity`:

```
class EventActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: EventViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EventViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.insertionId.observe(this, android.arch.lifecycle.Observer { id ->
            // Use `id` for example to update UI. 
        })

        // ...

        viewModel.insert(Event("name"))
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to be a better solution. But I'm just wandering, is my request an anti-pattern? Is it necessary to check the insert/delete result?

Comment: Sure you can check the result, it's up to you. For example, when you check insertion result and it fails, you can show some error message to the user if he/she should know about the error.

Answer (score 2):

```
  suspend fun insert(data: String): String = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    //put logic here
    cont.resume("Done")

    //if error use this
    cont.resumeWithException(Exception("Error"))
  }
```

i can remove callback in this function with return and wait the return

```
  fun insertData(){
    GlobalScope.launch {
      val status = insert("This is Data!")

      if( status == "Done"){
      }else{
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is that mean I need to implement a new `scope` in `Activity` to invoke `insert(event: Event)`?

Answer (score 2):

> But is there any better solution?

i think there is.

in `androidx.lifecycle.*:2.2.0 alpha01` the 
`liveData { . . . }` , `emit()` functions are available.

you can rewrite your code in `viewModel` like this.

```
fun insertData(event: String) = liveData {
        val id = mEventDao.insertEvent(event)
        emit(id)
    }
```

and in your activity observe it.

```
viewModel.insertData("YourEvent").observe(this) {
            updateUi(id)
    }
```

don't forget to change your `Dao` methods to `suspend`

```
@Dao
interface EventDao {
    suspend fun insertEvent(event: Event): Long
}
```

BTW at this time the latest version of live data is `2.2.0-rc03`

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0-rc03"
```

you can see better implementation in android documentation : [Use coroutines with LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata)

Answer (score 0):

@rofie-sagara is completely right. You can add `suspend` to your's model `insert` method. But it's not necessary to use `suspendCoroutine` syntax. You can write in your model

```
class ViewModel {
    private val job = Job()
    private val scope: CoroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + job)
    private val dao = Dao()

    suspend fun insert(event: Event): Long =
        withContext(scope.coroutineContext) {
            try {
                // just for testing delay situation
                delay(5000)
                dao.insert(event)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                -1L
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Is that mean I need to implement a new `scope` in `Activity` to invoke `insert(event: Event)`?

Comment: Yes, if you want for example show on your activity the result of this operation. Otherwise, if you want fire-and-forget this insertion you can use GlobalScope.